# How to integrate adobe CC 2014 with Laravel 4

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-4, dreamweaver

Problem:

When designing with Dreamweaver CC and using Laravel 4 blade templating engine, the CSS files are placed in the `/public` folder while the `*.blade.php` template is placed in the `/app/views/` directory.

How can edit/fix/design those blase `*.blade.php` files in CC 'live view' when those CSS files are not (reachable?) by Dreamweaver.

Basically, how can we integrate Laravel and Dreamwaever CC for using 'live view'?

Comment: You can't 'make' dreamwaver showing everything. I think dreamwaver doesn't support any kind of the laravel files. I would say, don't use dreamwaver.

Comment: What do you recommend using instead of Dreamweaver?

Comment: I use sublime Text 3 and it does have an plugin for the laravel blade. I like the UI of sublime.

Comment: Nope, im looking more for a WYSIWYG editor for the graphical interface, not a code editor.

Comment: Can I ask why? Because if you work with Laravel I think you're an back-end developer. So you acctually need the graphical interface. Or are you an front-end developer? Then you don't need to use laravel imo

Comment: Yes, sure: I'm a one man team, it's frustrating when i have to make small changes to my design or correct layout issues when using Laravel Blade.

Comment: I'm also a one man team, I also use laravel, No issues for me tho. don't knwo why you want this?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, here is what encounter today: i decided to format my validation errors in a different way, i fire up Dreamweaver and opened my form.blade.php, i like to test the way that is going to look using the live view feature, but here is the problem: i cant cause Dreamweaver cant find the css files and also doesn't know what {{ form::open }} is. how would you accomplish this task since you have don't have this kind of issues? maybe you have a different approach?

Comment: You can't drramwaver renders only html. When you try to access the {{ }} method, you call to a php file (a controller) and that doesn't Dreamwaver render. So you can't use Dreamwaver for your actions. You can try insttalling your own server on your local device.

Comment: I have wamp installed, i test everything on my local machine, so know you why this is so frustrating to go back and forth whenever i have to make layout changes.